# Set selected of Paper-Tabs

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

I am trying to select a `paper-tab` based on it's `data-id` attribute. I have the element but I cannot changed to `selected` property of the `inner_tabview`.

I have a Polymer:

```
<paper-tabs id="inner_tabview" noink="true">
    <template repeat="{{item in tabNames}}">
        <paper-tab data-id="{{item['id']}}"><h3>{{item['name']}}</h3></paper-tab>
    </template>
</paper-tabs>
```

And some Dart code behind it:

```
selectTab(itemId) {     
    PaperTab item = shadowRoot.querySelector("paper-tab[data-id='" + itemId + "']");
    print('Selecting: ' + itemId + ', text:' + item.text);

    PaperTabs tabView = shadowRoot.querySelector('#inner_tabview');
    tabView.selected = item; // This doesn't work
}
```

Changing the selected using an integer (index) works, but I don't know what the index should be.

Only thing I can currently think of is finding all `paper-tab` elements and get the index of the correct element in that `List`. But that sounds a bit silly to do so.

Any other way?

Comment: Have you checked in the Chrome devtools that the `data-id` attribute actually has a value assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why `querySelector` doesn't work but `selected` expects an index by default not an element.

if you specify the `valueattr` attribute you can use other attributes than the index.

```dart
<paper-tabs id="inner_tabview" noink="true" valueattr="data-id">
    <template repeat="{{item in tabNames}}">
        <paper-tab data-id="{{item['id']}}"><h3>{{item['name']}}</h3></paper-tab>
    </template>
</paper-tabs>
```

then

```dart
tabView.selected = itemId;
```

should work as well

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the valueattr

Comment: The querySelector works, but I could not change the selected property.

Comment: Difficult to tell with the available information. Can you share a sample project via GitHub?